# Define Font Substitution Table in iOS App

Tags: ios, fonts

Is there a way to define a font substitution table in an iOS app?

The goal is predetermine what font UIWebView uses when a specific font isn't available...

Answer (score 0):

change your webview's font like as follows

```
NSString *body = @"YOUR STRING";
NSString *htmlString = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<font face='GothamRounded-Bold' size='3'>%@", body];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: you can even do this to set the font                                    use this   [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.body.style.fontFamily = 'GothamRounded-Bold'"];